# numpy array difference to the largest value in another large array which less than the original array

Tags: arrays, numpy, numba

numpy experts,

I'm using numpy.
I want to compare two arrays, get the largest value that is smaller than one of the arrays, and calculate the difference between them.

For example,

```
A = np.array([3, 5, 7, 12, 13, 18])
B = np.array([4, 7, 17, 20])
```

I want `[1, 0, 4, 2]` (4-3, 7-7, 17-13, 20-18) , in this case.
The problem is that the size of the A and B arrays is so large that it would take a very long time to do this by simple means. I can try to divide them to some size, but I wonder if there is a simple numpy function to solve this problem.
Or can I use numba?

For your information, This is my current very stupid codes.

```
delta = np.zeros_like(B)
for i in range(len(B)):    
    index_A = (A <= B[i]).argmin() - 1
    delta[i] = B[i] - A[index_A]
```

Comment: The problem is that darn for loop that you are using. Since Python is an interpreted language it is around 100x or more slower than a built in function. Would a cython-based solution work for you (rather than numba)?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @tarlen555 that the problem is mostly related to the for-loop. I guess this one is already much faster:

```py
diff = B-A[:,np.newaxis]
diff[diff<0] = max(A.max(), B.max())
diff.min(axis=0)
```

In the second line, I wanted to fill all entries with negative values with something ridiculously large. Since your numbers are integer, `np.inf` doesn't work, but something like that could be more elegant.

EDIT:

Another way:

```py
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
tree = cKDTree(A.reshape(-1, 1))
k = 2
large_value = max(A.max(), B.max())
while True:
    indices = tree.query(B.reshape(-1, 1), k=k)[1]
    diff = B[:,np.newaxis]-A[indices]
    if np.all(diff.max(axis=-1)>=0):
        break
    k += 1
diff[diff<0] = large_value
diff.min(axis=1)
```

This solution *could* be more memory-efficient but frankly I'm not sure how much more.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, in my case, A and B is much large thus unable to allocate `diff = B-A[:,np.newaxis]` in this line.

Comment: I edited my comment, in the hope that the new version will be more helpful. But to be honest I'm not really sure if it's really much better.